# How to remove unwanted extra root commit in git repository?

Tags: git

I recently converted a subversion repo, which had been converted from cvs before that and I've ended up with the following structure (simplified for clarity) at the bottom of the tree:

```
* master
|
...
|
|
* G 
|\
| * F
| * E
| * D
| * C Initial commit.
|
|
* A New repository initialized by cvs2svn.
```

The line from G-A contained unwanted commits which I've removed successfully with "git filter-branch". I'd like to be able to remove that line entirely, including the initial
empty root commit at A and just have a single line going back to C.

So I'd like to remove A as a parent of G and allow it to be gc'd, but I'm not sure if that's possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`git filter-branch`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch) with a `--parent-filter` on G:

```
$ git filter-branch --parent-filter \
    'test $GIT_COMMIT = G && echo "-p F" || cat' HEAD
```

where you replace `G` and `F` with the actual SHA-1 values.

Comment: Thanks. That was spot on. The only difference was that I ended up using "-- --all" instead of "HEAD", as there were actually multiple branches which had G as an ancestor.